# Is there a way to send remote notification only when receiver's app is active?

Tags: ios, ios7

I want to send remote notifications to a user, but also don't want to disturb them so much. Thus for some kind of notifications I only want the receivers to be notified when they are using the app at the moment.

Meanwhile, I also want some other notifications to trigger a banner and/or an alert.

Is there any way to do so?

Plus, I am using iOS 7.

Comment: It's possible but not with APNS. Check this out [libPusher](https://github.com/lukeredpath/libPusher)

Comment: For the notifications simply don't use APNS. Just query the server from the app when it's fired up and simply show some alert if needed. Don't try to hack around with push notifications, it's not a good idea.

Comment: It is possible. but depends on few situations like do you need to send and pending notifications sent to device when app become active.

Comment: ask you web service team to write a service for user status where when the user is in active state send userID and status as "1". when app enters background state you need to send UserID and status as "0". Any how notifications will be sent by them to APNS server so while sending notification to perticular user they have to check status and then they need to send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. I also want some other notifications to trigger a banner and/or an alert.

its not possible. Push notification will only as configured by the user. if ur app in runnin foregroung u can rise custom notification alert.

> I want to send remote notifications to user, but also don't want to
>   disturb them so much. Thus for some kinds of notifications I only want
>   the receivers to be notified when they are using the app at the
>   moment.

u need to track the user who or all using ur application by intimate ur server from app delegates

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

intimate the server that app is not using by  user.

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
```

intimate the server that app is currently using by  user.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly. You could send a push notification that does not display a banner or play a sound and then in the app check whether or not your running in the foreground. If you are you can display a local notification.